# $P(a < X \leq b) = F(b) - F(a)$?

Tags: probability

Let X be a random variable with distribution function F, $a,b \in \Re$ with $a \lt b$ and $F(x-)$ is the limit of $F$ in $x$ from the left.

I tried to proof that the equality is correct, but I'm stuck by not comprehending what to do next, so far I had:

$(x,y] = (-\infty,y]-(-\infty,x]$

$\Rightarrow \forall x \in \Re$ we have

$F_X(x)=P(X \leq x) = P(X \in (-\infty,x])$

Then I assume that I need to prove that the continuity property of distribution functions from the right still satisfied, but I don't know how to do it with this elements. Can someone clear my mind a little bit? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea. Since $(-\infty,a]$ and $(a, b]$ are disjoint, you have
$$P(X \in (-\infty, a]) + P(X \in (a, b]) = P(X \in (-\infty, a] \cup (a, b]) = P(X \in (-\infty, b]).$$